# Returning Event Handler for an event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know if is possible to get the event handler for any events in JavaScript that was set for an object using `addEventListener` or `on("event",...)` in jQuery.

The idea is to return a function object and then reassign that function object to another events, for example an event handler A was set for an event 'click' but remotely. then after loading the script remotely, i want to modify this event and set the event handler to point to focus instead of `onclick`. I have no either so i can't drop a code sample.

I am expecting a function object to reassign to another event type

Comment: No, that's not possible. Regarding your remote clicks, you might be able to trigger an event on the original element from the remote location though.

Comment: With modern browser APIs (`addEventListener()`, not that modern really) and jQuery, there may be more than one event handler for any given element. There may also be a delegation system in effect (esp. with jQuery) meaning that an event handler for an element may actually be a handler for some parent element (like `document` or `document.body`). In general what you're asking would be very complicated.

Comment: Actually is hacking Mister, but well is clear to me now is not possible. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Listeners attached with `addEventListener` cannot be fetched.

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function(){alert("clicked");});
```

The best shot will be

```
document.getElementById("clickMe").click();
```

Listener attached using the HTML node onclick property like:

```
<button id="clickMe" onclick="alert('clicked');">Click Me</button>
```

can be fetched as

```
var handler=document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick;
```